# Testthat fails when setting up rms by calling datadist() + options()

Tags: r, testthat

I'm trying to do some unit testing using the `testthat` package but I can't seem to get it to work properly together with the `rms` package. The following example:

```
library(rms)
set.seed(10)
ds <- data.frame(
  ftime = rexp(200),
  fstatus = sample(0:1,200,replace=TRUE),
  x1 = runif(200),
  x2 = runif(200),
  x3 = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], size=200, replace=TRUE)))


ddist <- datadist(ds)
options(datadist="ddist")

s <- Surv(ds$ftime, ds$fstatus == 1)
fit <- cph(s ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=ds)
```

returns this error:

> Error in Design(eval.parent(m)) : 
>    dataset ddist not found for options(datadist=)

This even though print(ddist) works and the options("datadist") returns the proper variable. Does `testthat` have a different variable scope that causes errors?

### Update

I run the testthat by a R console started in the my package dir (Eclipse StatET):

```
library(testthat)
test_dir("inst/tests")
q()
```

The same error occurs with the R CMD check --as-cran

Comment: @agstudy: Added how I run the testthat

Comment: <shrug> Both Professors Harrell and Wickham have (or had) been known to resort to programming techniques which may be or may not be close to those of R Core.  As such, side effects lasting longer than four hours may occur. I think you may just have met one.  There are two other unit testing packages you could try if you want to keep the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) around.

Comment: Unable to reproduce so far. R 2.15.2, MacOS 10.6.8, R.app GUI 1.53 (6335), `testthat` version 0.7, `evaluate` 0.4.2 (and re-tested with `evaluate` 0.4.3). Perhaps it is problem with the usual paths being hijacked by StatET? I do not know what you mean by same error with: `R CMD check --as-cran` Is that the complete command line entry (which gave an error when I entered it, but nothing to do with `rms`)?

Comment: @DWin: I use Windows 7, R 2.15.2 64-bit, testthat v 0.7, evaluate 0.4.3 and the latest rms package 3.6-2. The R CMD thing is just the cran check for my package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I really like the tools that come in the Hmisc/rms packages and my own package is intended to supplement some of them, like a markdown alternative to latex(). The reason that I'm setting up the unit testing is to see if I can understand some of the code by restructuring the Predict(), predictrms(), contrast() and summary.rms() - they all have their own calculation of the confidence interval. This seems to me like a bad idea especially since it seems that the Predict() is the only one that properly deals with the bootstrapped estimates (with coef.reps=TRUE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes It is a scope problem as suggested by the error.

A possible work around is to define your `ds` where you call `test_dir`

for example You create file, `runtest.R` like this

```
library(rms)
set.seed(10)
ds <- data.frame(
  ftime = rexp(200),
  fstatus = sample(0:1,200,replace=TRUE),
  x1 = runif(200),
  x2 = runif(200),
  x3 = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], size=200, replace=TRUE)))
ddist <- datadist(ds)
options(datadist="ddist")
library(testthat)
test_dir("inst/tests")
```

Answer (score 5):

While @agstudy's suggestion is correct I've figured out a simple workaround for the bug by using the **<<-** operator that assigns the variable to the global environment, here's a test-file that works:

```
set.seed(10)
n <- 11
ds <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(n),
  x1 = factor(sample(c("a", "aa", "aaa"), size = n, replace = TRUE)))

suppressMessages(library(rms))
dd <<- datadist(ds)
options(datadist = "dd")

context("rms")
test_that("test", {
  fit <- ols(y ~ x1, data=ds)
  s <- summary(fit)
  expect_true(inherits(s, "summary.rms"))
})
```

This works also if you happen to do the assignment within the `test_that`:

```
context("rms")
test_that("test", {
  set.seed(10)
  n <- 11
  ds <- data.frame(
    y = rnorm(n),
    x1 = factor(sample(c("a", "aa", "aaa"), size = n, replace = TRUE)))

  suppressMessages(library(rms))
  dd <<- datadist(ds)
  options(datadist = "dd")

  fit <- ols(y ~ x1, data=ds)
  s <- summary(fit)
  expect_true(inherits(s, "summary.rms"))
})
```

This is also equivalent to the following code (perhaps easier to understand):

```
env <- globalenv() # Grab the global environment
env$dd <- datadist(ds) # Assign the datadist to it
```

If you want to learn more about how environments work I can recommend Hadley's excellent Advanced R coverage of the [topic](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html). I found this explaining many of the issues that I was running into.